# Run resource method before each request

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I have some code where one parameter (a cookie) can be passed to any of the paths, and I want to handle it the same way:

```
@Path("/some/path")
public class JaxRsService {

    public void doStuff(@CookieParam("cookie") Cookie cookie) {
        handleCookie(cookie);
        // etc.
    }

    public void doStuff2(@CookieParam("cookie") Cookie cookie) {
        handleCookie(cookie);
        // etc.
    }

    public void doStuff3(@CookieParam("cookie") Cookie cookie) {
        handleCookie(cookie);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Is there a way to factor this out of each method? I tried creating a setter, but setters only get called at construction time, so the cookie isn't available..

```
@Path("/some/path")
public class JaxRsService {

    // This never gets called
    @CookieParam("cookie")
    public void setCookie(Cookie cookie) {
       cookie // stuff
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Similarly, there's the `@PostContruct` annotation, but it only works on construct time.

Adding the cookie as a class variable works fine, but I'd still have to call the method in every request:

```
@Path("/some/path")
public class JaxRsService {

    // This never gets called
    @CookieParam("cookie")
    Cookie cookie;

    public void doStuff() {
        handleCookie();
        // etc.
    }

    public void doStuff2() {
        handleCookie();
        // etc.
    }

    public void doStuff3() {
        handleCookie();
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Is there any nice way to handle this?

Comment: Is this a top-level resource or a sub-resource?

Comment: @DonalFellows - It's a top-level resource. I guess I could use a subresource locator and some magic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CXF the "interceptors" are the standard way of decorating a request. I don't know of a portable method, though.

... another method may be (proprietary, too) http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html (which is nearly the same in essence)